# Почему нельзя написать "неатлет"

Tags: морфология, словообразование

> Он *неспециалист*.
>
> Он **не** *атлет*.

Я не могу сказать *неатлет*. Нужно заранее знать с какими существительными *не* можно писать слитно, а с какими нет, или есть какие-то общие правила?

Comment: 《Я не могу сказать _неатлет_》 ╱ А я могу. :-) Нет, серьезно, не вижу препятствий.

Comment: [Вот несколько беллетристов](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82&hl=en&tbm=bks) и их редактора тоже не видят.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: Профессия редактора русских текстов за последние двадцать лет практически полностью утратила профессионализм, а с ним и какой-либо авторитет.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Мне кажется, что ни *Он неспециалист*, ни *Он неатлет* писать нельзя, так как это не утверждения **непринадлежности** "к какому-либо разряду лиц или явлений", а напротив, отрицания **принадлежности** к этим разрядам:

> *Приглашали специалистов, а он не специалист*.
>   *На Олимпиаду едут атлеты, а я не атлет*.

Напротив, все примеры из правила, приведённого @Vitaly, как раз утверждают или подчёркивают именно **непринадлежность** упоминаемых людей, предметов или явлений к подразумеваемым ограниченным группам или классам или, точнее, их **принадлежность** к пространству **за пределами** этих классов

> Нелингвист не напишет такой диктант (а лингвист напишет). 
>   Неакадемические институты (в отличие от академических).
>   Неспециалист только испортит всё дело.
>   Неатлеты первыми сошли с дистанции.

Я предлагаю упрощённую формулировку правила:

> Утверждение **непринадлежности** — слитно; отрицание **принадлежности** — раздельно.

Comment: Вот чёткий ответ! Так сказать, дифдиагноз - конкретные критерии для различения ситуаций.

Answer (score 4):

Я предполагаю, что все же «неатлет» можно (и даже нужно) писать слитно.

> § 148. С существительными, прилагательными, наречиями на *-о* отрицание *не* пишется слитно в следующих случаях.
>
> <...>
>
> 2. Если существительные и прилагательные в сочетании с не обозначают непринадлежность к какому-либо разряду лиц или явлений, напр.: *неврачи, нефранцузы, немарксисты, нехристиане, неспециалисты, немосквичи, нерусские, недемократы, непоэты, нетермины, неметаллы, нестихи; Нерусский взглянет без любви / На эту бледную, в крови, / Кнутом иссеченную музу* (Некр.); *Неврач не разберётся в этом; Неспециалистам доклад понравился; Неегиптолог его не поймёт; Нематематику не решить этой задачи; Нелингвист не напишет такой диктант; неакадемические институты, непищевые добавки, невоенные отрасли.*
>
> <...>

— [Полный академический справочник под ред. В. В. Лопатина.](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3883)

Comment: Но не в данном случае. Что-нибудь вроде "Среди неатлетов этот статистический показатель совсем иной" — да, но "Он не_атлет" вряд ли при каком угодно контексте оправданно будет написать слитно.

Comment: @NikolayErshov, да, но и _«Он не[ ]специалист»_, писать слитно тоже не всегда оправдано. В том смысле, что никакой разницы меж _неспециалистом_ и _неатлетом_ все-равно нет — просто первое употребляется весьма часто, а второе еще поискать надо. Но причина тому не грамматическая.

Answer (score 1):

Я не носитель языка, но мне кажется, что можно придумать ситуацию для любого такого "странного" слова, когда оно как раз звучит совсем нормально. Например, если гуглить "неатлет", есть некоторые примеры, которые по-моему совершенно приемлемы.

Answer (score 1):

Основное правило: если не+что-то можно заменить на одно слово без существенной потери смысла, то *не* пишется слитно, иначе - раздельно.
Это относится к существительным, прилагательным и наречиям.
[Ссылку](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3883) на более подробное правило дал Виталий.

Можно также перевести фразу на английский или другой язык с похожей структурой. Слитное не чаще всего будет соответствовать "non", a раздельное - "not":

- *я неатлет*  ~ *I am а non-athlete*.
- *я не атлет* ~ *I am not an athlete*.